# Exception querying table with dynamic columns from .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Some time ago I explained my problem in this question [Is this a "correct" database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10427441/1061499)

Basically, I have a relational DB containing tables with dynamic columns, so I don't have a fixed structure for some of these tables and sometimes when I try to retrieve data from them is really problematic.

Now I'm developing a web app that point to this DB and I'm using this code to execute query:

```
IEnumerable<Result> res = db.ExecuteQuery<Result>(@"SELECT * FROM ENTITY_PROPERTIES_1 WHERE EntityID = {0}), entity.ID);
```

But every time the table structure changes I get this error:

> {"The OLE DB provider \"SQLNCLI10\" for linked server \"DATA-DB2\" reported a change in schema version between compile time (\"178395762719197\") and run time (\"178408647621334\") for table \"\"icrm_ca\".\"dbo\".\"ENTITY_PROPERTIES_1\"\"."}

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using a synonym for the linked server's objects?

Comment: @SNash Yes, I think the problem is this...

Answer (score 0):

If Are you using a synonym for the linked server's objects. Run the following code:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

which removes all cache entries.